# Crop image and take the left part with ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, filter, ffmpeg, crop

```
ffmpeg -i giphy.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[left];[1:v]crop=iw/2:ih:ow:0[right];[left][right]hstack" -vframes 1 -vcodec mjpeg giphy.jpg
```

The command above takes the first frame of a mp4 file and converts it to an image. I want to crop that image and take only the left part starting from center but I get the following error:

> Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description
>   [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[left];[1:v]crop=iw/2:ih:ow:0[right];[left][right]hstack.

What is wrong with my command? The image I want to crop: imgur.com/a/PdAqiZU -> I want to take only the left part of that image

Comment: *take only the left part starting from center* --> not clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: The image I want to crop: https://imgur.com/a/PdAqiZU -> I want to take only the left part of that image

Answer (score 1):

You just need one crop filter.

```
ffmpeg -i giphy.mp4 -vf "crop=iw/2:ih:0:0" -vframes 1 giphy.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know the crop command for nodejs package?